# Ember CLI livereload does not detect changes

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

### Livereload

I'm having problems getting Ember CLI (1.13.15) to detect changes. When I create a new application with

```
ember init
```

And run the development server with

```
ember serve
```

The project compiles and I see the page. When I change something, the server detects changes in the console, but nothing happens even if I refresh page. The changes become visible only after I rerun the `ember serve`

### Slow build

Also on an empty app it takes 30 sec to build app on Samsung 850 Pro SSD & i7 2600k with admin rights and after *ember-cli-windows* run. (the build on half slower MacBook Air is almost instantaneous).

### Versions

- Windows 10 with all the updates
- ember-cli: 1.13.15
- node: 4.2.6
- npm: 2.14.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the best solution seems to be sticking to the old versions. Also there seems to be an issue with latest **sass** plugin not recognizing changes so I recommend downgrading both to:

```
ember-cli: 1.13.8,
ember-cli-sass: 4.2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this as well -- seemingly out of nowhere, at once, on several different projects. Making sure I had this in `.ember-cli` was a winning fix:

```
"liveReload": true,
"watcher": "polling"
```

**[Update]**
I already had `liveReload: true`, so adding the `watcher` setting seems to be what was needed. Furthermore the projects that I implemented this for were using ember-cli at `1.13.13`, `2.2.0-beta.6` and `2.3.0-beta.1`, with the following system config:

```
node: 4.2.4
npm: 2.14.10
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: Just checked this and it doesn't seem to help. I see the change being detected by watcher (takes about 30 sec to compile), but the page itself doesn't change, even after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a known issue in ember-cli where the open port for livereload isn't detected correctly (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/5391). You should be able to get around this for now by running `ember serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The dev server starts and i can see the output in the browser, but when i change something, it still doesn't recognize the changes